# Titanium version of TapkuLibrary

Tags: mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

Is there a port of TapkuLibrary for Ti?
I'm looking for a calendar(view) control in Titanium, but there's really nothing that works exactly the way Tapku's does.

Is it possible to use the TapkuLibrary's classes in Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is use only for xCode (SDK)not for Titanium. you Can use [this](https://github.com/Mritunjaysingh/Titanium-Calendar) for iOS and it is fine. 
and android have default titanium Calendar functions.